# Youtube video slow on one platform

Tags: video, linux, youtube, windows-7

On my laptop, I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.10 set up to dual boot.  When I'm on Windows, Youtube is really slow, but on Ubuntu its very fast even with HD videos.

Why is that, and what can I do to fix this Windows problem?

Comment: We need more information. Which browsers are you using? 32-bit or 64-bit OS? Which version of Adobe Flash Player is installed? Do you notice that your network is generally slower on Windows? What are your computer specifications? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on a lot which just comes down to (in a nutshell) the amount of resources that are being used on the computer. We could get into a browser battle here, but you might want to see what is going on with your windows platform first.